# Finding letters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, findall

I'm trying to write a code that finds the letters in a string containing special characters, numbers and letters. The following code returns nothing:

```
a ="&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
print(a)
final = a.split()
for y in final:
    if (y.isalpha == True):
        print(y)
```

Output: &*&)*&gokjhohgouigougyy^&*^x
=> None

Can someone tell me what is the issue and how can I do it without using the `re.findall`, e.g. using loops like:

```
for(y in final):
    if (ord(y) in range (97, 127)):
        print(y)
```

The above code works:

```
for y in a:
    if (ord(y) in range (97, 127)):
        print(y, end='')
```

Comment: why you do splitting?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: To try and convert to a list and see if that helps. Not sure it does help though

Comment: `re.findall(r'[a-z]+', a)`

Comment: also, you are splitting with a `space` character (or some whitespace character, yet there are no spaces in your string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't want to use findall

Comment: @pythonnewbie this won't actually need `re.findall` but I think you failed to explain your question with expected output.

Comment: @pythonnewbie - split() is the same as split(' ')! A single space is the default arg.

Comment: @pythonnewbie. Do you want a list just the letters from the string?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes just extract the alphabets from the string,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `y.isalpha` as `y.isalpha()` this is because isalpha is a function or method.

```
>>> y='y'
>>> y.isalpha
<built-in method isalpha of str object at 0x00FA3A40>
>>> y.isalpha()
True
```

Note that your split will give you words not letters - which may not be what you are expecting:

```
>>> s = "Yes! These are words."
>>> for w in s.split(' '):
...    print(w, w.isalpha())
...
Yes! False
These True
are True
words. False
>>>
```

One of the things to get used to in python is the difference between a property and a method - a property is something that you can read a method performs some action - `dir` lists both so for a string `s` you have:

```
>>> dir(s)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
 '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 
 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_map', 'index', 'isalnum',
 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 
 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join',
 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind',
 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines',
 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill'
]
```

Where:

```
>>> s.__class__
<class 'str'>
```

is a property and:

```
>>> s.capitalize
<built-in method capitalize of str object at 0x03529F50>
```

is a method and needs to be called by the addition of parenthesis () to actually perform their function.  It is worth also distinguishing between methods that return a value and those that operate in place.

```
>>> s.lower()
'yes! these are words.'
```

Returns a value as does `s.split()` but `sort` is an in-place operation, e.g.:

```
>>> words = s.lower().split()
>>> words
['yes!', 'these', 'are', 'words.']
>>> words.sort()
>>> words
['are', 'these', 'words.', 'yes!']
>>>
```

Comment: 'Call' as in? I'm sorry i'm new to python, hence the stupid question

Comment: @pythonnewbie - I have expanded the answer above.

Comment: "call" -- as in "call a function". like dialing up a function on the phone, telling it some things (arguments), and listening to what it says back (returns) :)

Answer (score 2):

Splitting a string returns a list of substrings. For example: "abc def ghi".split(" ") returns ["abc", "def", "ghi"].
You needn't split the string for what you're trying. Just loop over the string itself.

```
string = "&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
for char in string:
    if char.isalpha():
        print(char)
```

Comment: I was just trying to convert it into a list and see if that makes the search easier. Screwed up the syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split it up and you should call `isalpha` as `isalpha()` instead because they are different things. This should print all the letters in what i assume is the format you want.

```
a ="&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
print(a)

for y in a:
    if y.isalpha():
        print(y)
```

Comment: you don't need brackets in the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks more like you want to *remove* unwanted characters from the string, rather than find those to retain.

So, if you want to print the result:

```
a ="&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
for c in a:
    if c.isalpha():
        print(c)
```

Output:

```
g
o
k
...
y
y
x
```

But usually you would want to assign the filtered string to a variable, like this which combines a generator comprehension with the `join()` string function:

```
a ="&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
s = ''.join(c for c in a if c.isalpha())
print(s)
```

Output:

gokjhohgouigougyyx

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton. I figured I wasn't calling isalpha in the right way.  What makes you think i was trying to 'remove' the unwanted elements rather than extract the 'relevant' ones? Just curious if there's a difference in the way python makes both work

Comment: @pythonnewbie: they are essentially the same :) I initially misread your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list use a list comprehension:

```
print([ch for ch in a if ch.isalpha()])
['g', 'o', 'k', 'j', 'h', 'o', 'h', 'g', 'o', 'u', 'i', 'g', 'o', 'u', 'g', 'y', 'y', 'x']
```

If you want to remove punctuation, digits and spaces from the string you can use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
from string import punctuation, digits

tbl = str.maketrans({ord(ch):"" for ch in punctuation+digits+" "})

print(a.translate(tbl))

gokjhohgouigougyyx
```

The `tbl` is just the `ord` of each character we want to replace with the value we want to replace it with which in this case is an empty string.

Comment: Would there be a difference in the above algorithm and that using isalpha/loop to extract the alphabets in terms of time, memory etc?

Comment: @pythonnewbie. If you had large strings .translate will beat any other option.  If you wanted a list the comprehension is faster than using a normal loop

Comment: Oh! thanks. Will look up its usage and try. Thanks a ton for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get clever you could also look at using a filter object:

```
>>> def isalpha(c):
...    """ Check if a character is a member of the alphabet """
...    return c.isalpha()
...
>>> s = "This string, or sentence, should have __no__ non-alphabetic characters in it!"
>>> f = filter(isalpha, s)
>>> ''.join(f)
'Thisstringorsentenceshouldhavenononalphabeticcharactersinit'
```

This can be shortened to:

```
>>> s="This string, or sentence, should have __no__ non-alphabetic characters in it!"
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda a: a.isalpha(), s))
'Thisstringorsentenceshouldhavenononalphabeticcharactersinit'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
a = "&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
for character in a:
    if character.isalpha():
        print(character)
```

If you also wanted to count the letters, you could do it using a dictionary and a list:

```
di = dict()
a = "&*&)*&GOKJHOHGOUIGougyY^&*^x".lower()
for character in a:
    if character.isalpha():
        di[character] = di.get(character,0) + 1

lst = sorted([(v,k) for k,v in di.items()], reverse=True)
for v, k in lst:
    print(k, v)
```

That should print the letters in decreasing order of frequency.